# Select chart object based on position in sheet (VBA)

Tags: vba, charts

Is there a possibility to address a chart object in an excel sheet via its exact position? Google didn't help so far so any input is appreciated.

Best regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `TopLeftCell` and `BottomRightCell` to find a chart between given range.

```
Sub testChart()
 Dim oChart As Chart

 '/ Selecet the chart , if found in Range D4:F10
 Set oChart = findChart(Sheet1.Range("D4:F10"))
 If Not oChart Is Nothing Then
    oChart.Parent.Select
 Else
    MsgBox "No chart found."
 End If

End Sub

Function findChart(ByVal rngChart As Range) As Chart

    Dim oChart      As Chart
    Dim oChartObj   As ChartObject
    Dim wksChart    As Worksheet
    Dim rngCArea    As Range

    Set wksChart = rngChart.Parent

    For Each oChartObj In wksChart.ChartObjects
         Set rngCArea    = Intersect(wksChart.Range(rngChart.Address), wksChart.Range(oChartObj.TopLeftCell, oChartObj.BottomRightCell))
         If Not rngCArea Is Nothing Then
          Set oChart = oChartObj.Chart
         End If
    Next

    Set findChart = oChart

End Function
```

Comment: if this solutions works then mark it as answered: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow