# Is there a way to list chart numbers based on position in the spreadsheet? (Not in sorted order?)

Tags: excel, vba

The following macro lists all the chart numbers of by worksheet but it order them and this is not how the charts appear in the sheet.

```
Sub ListChartNames()
Dim Cht As ChartObject
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
For Each Cht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
Cells(i, 1) = Cht.Chart.Name
i = i + 1
Next Cht
End Sub
```

For example, I have a chart in E6:L17 (let's call this one Chart 1) and another in N6:U17 (let's call this one Chart 11).
Then, I move down to two charts in E19:L30 (let's call this one Chart 400) and another in N19:U30 (let's call this one Chart 2).
Then, I move down to two charts in E32:L43 (let's call this one Chart 3) and another in N32:U43 (let's call this one Chart 12)
Then, I move down to only 1 chart in E45:L56 (let's call this one Chart 13)
Then, I back to two charts in E58:L69 and another in N58:U69 (let's call these Chart 15 and Chart 16)
and so on.....

The above charts are all in columns E through U. But then there is another set in columns Y through AO in same patter and again in AS through BI, etc.

I have like 500 charts and I'd like a macro to list them starting in the first set of columns (E through L) but list them from top to bottom, let to right.

So, the results based on the above would be for columns F through U
Chart 1
Chart 11
Chart 400
Chart 2
Chart 3
Chart 12
Chart 13
Chart 15
Chart 16

The macro above lists the charts in a sorted order which is not what I need.

This also doesn't answer the question: [Select chart object based on position in sheet (VBA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38520111/select-chart-object-based-on-position-in-sheet-vba)

Answer (score 0):

Does this give you what you need?

```
Sub list_charts_in_top_left_to_bottom_right()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, outputsh As Worksheet, last_cell As Range, oChartObj As Object
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetWithChartsOnIt")
    Set outputsh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetToWriteTo")
    
    outputsh.Range("A:A").ClearContents
    
    outputsh.Range("A1") = "Output:"
    
    If ws.ChartObjects.Count = 0 Then
        outputsh.Range("A2") = "No charts found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Debug.Print "Charts found: " & ws.ChartObjects.Count
    
    Set last_cell = ws.Range("A1")
    
    'find bounds of range by expanding last_cell with each chart
    For Each oChartObj In ws.ChartObjects
        With oChartObj

            If .TopLeftCell.Row > last_cell.Row Then Set last_cell = ws.Cells(.TopLeftCell.Row, last_cell.Column)
            If .TopLeftCell.Column > last_cell.Column Then Set last_cell = ws.Cells(last_cell.Row, .TopLeftCell.Column)
        End With
    Next
    
    Debug.Print "Bounds of range: $A$1:" & last_cell.Address

    Dim area_to_examine As Range

    For col = 5 To last_cell.Column Step 21 'start with column 5 (E) and then jump 21 columns at a time
    
    Set area_to_examine = Range(Columns(col), Columns(col + 17))
    
    Debug.Print "Examining: " & area_to_examine.Address
    
        For Each rw In Intersect(area_to_examine, ws.Range("A1", last_cell.Address).Rows)
            For Each cl In rw.Cells
                For Each oChartObj In ws.ChartObjects
                    With oChartObj
                        If .TopLeftCell.Row = cl.Row And .TopLeftCell.Column = cl.Column Then
                        outputsh.Cells(outputsh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = .Name
                        Debug.Print .Name
                        End If
                    End With
                Next
            Next
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: nothing happens when I execute it.  Will this work if my sheet only has charts and nothing else written in any cells in the sheet?

Comment: No, it won't. I've added some code now to detect where the charts are without using the usedrange property of the sheet.

Comment: yeah - I looked in the immediate window and nothing was printed.  Similarly, with the above code, nothing is printed in column A in the active sheet when I execute.  Strange...

Comment: You do need to ensure the sheet full of charts is the ActiveSheet.

Comment: nothing in immediate window - and I definitely have the chart sheet as the active sheet.  Is the code to go in the sheet's code window or a module? Not sure that matters.

Comment: Another edit supplied. It needs to go in a module. You'll need to provide the name of the sheet to look for charts on and also the name of the sheet you want it to write the output to (which you'll need to create).

Comment: if column a is empty, it throws an error.  If I add data to cell A1, then it clears the column and the results show Output: in cell A1 but nothing else.

Comment: it's like it doesn't see the charts in the sheet

Comment: Are you now using the latest code, that writes to a sheet? If it can't see any charts in the chart sheet, it will report "no charts found".

Comment: I changed this and it looks like it is working

    Set last_cell = ws.Range("z1000")

Comment: I've no idea why you'd need to do that. Is it outputting the list correctly?

Comment: It is to a degree....I have different sets of charts...so there is a set between columns F through U and I wanted to the macro to isolate the charts in those columns first - and left to right from top to bottom, so top row, upper left chart listed first, then top row, upper right chart listed second, then next row of charts, then next row, etc.  Then after all the charts in columns E through U were listed, I wanted the cycle to repeat for the charts in columns Y through AO, ....and after those columns were done, then the next set of columns....there are 22 different column sets

Comment: I've made another edit. This now scans the sheet in batches of 17 columns, starting in column E and then jumping 21 columns and so on and so on.. I also found an issue with determining where the charts are, so you shouldn't need to force it out to z1000 now.

Comment: Thanks CLR!  It seems to work - but is super super slow....I have 902 charts and I think I'll have to run this overnight....seems like there would be an easier way to do it.  In any case, I am very thankful that you spent time on this. :)

Comment: I've only tested it with 8 charts so haven't noticed the speed issue. It's slow for you, because for each cell in the sheet, it loops through every chart to see if they sit in that cell. An alternative approach would be to create an array containing the row/column positions and then applying a specialist sort. If I have time, I'll look into that and if necessary publish a second answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative method. It's still not using a sort algo, but uses a workaround which (does waste a little time but) should be massively quicker than scanning every cell in the sheet:

```
Sub list_charts_in_top_left_to_bottom_right_v2()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, outputsh As Worksheet, chartCount As Long, x As Long, y As Long, maxZ As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetWithChartsOnIt")
    Set outputsh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetToWriteTo")
    
    outputsh.Range("A:A").ClearContents
    
    outputsh.Range("A1").Value = "Chart"
    chartCount = ws.ChartObjects.Count
    
    ReDim arrChartlist(chartCount, 1)
    
    If chartCount = 0 Then
        outputsh.Range("A2") = "No charts found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
           
    maxZ = 0
    
    For x = 0 To chartCount - 1
        With ws.ChartObjects(x + 1)
            arrChartlist(x, 0) = .Name
            arrChartlist(x, 1) = (((.TopLeftCell.Column - 2) \ 19) * chartCount * chartCount) + (.TopLeftCell.Column * chartCount) + .TopLeftCell.Row
            If maxZ < arrChartlist(x, 1) Then maxZ = arrChartlist(x, 1)
        End With
    Next

    For x = 0 To maxZ
        For y = 0 To chartCount - 1
            If x = arrChartlist(y, 1) Then
                outputsh.Cells(outputsh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = arrChartlist(y, 0)
            End If
        Next
    Next
      
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually - spoke too soon.  Assume there are 4 charts.  Upper left is 1, upper right is 2, lower left is 3, and lower right is 4.  These results create a list 1,3,2,4 is looks like....but the desired result is 1,2,3,4 (left to right from top to bottom - but restricted to the set of columns first...and then repeating an the next set of columns, etc.)  Still, I think I can work with this - way better than what I was doing before.

Comment: The important line in the code is the line that starts `arrChartlist(x, 1)` - this line essentially takes the position of the chart and attempts to 'score' that into a single figure, using the section first, then the column, then the row. It then dumps the list in order of that score, ascending. So if you can tweak that, you can modify the way it outputs.

Comment: I'll see what I can do - thanks again